# How fast can elliptic curve rank grow in towers of number fields?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Fix $E/K$ an elliptic curve over a number field $K$.  For various towers of finite field extensions $K=K_0 \subset K_1 \subset K_2\subset\cdots$ how fast can $\operatorname{rank}(E(K_n))$ grow in terms of $|K_n:K|$?

If $E:y^2=f(x)$ then there exist $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{f(x_n)} \notin K_{n-1} = K(\sqrt{f(x_1)},\sqrt{f(x_2)}, \ldots, \sqrt{f(x_{n-1})})$ and $P_n=(x_n,\sqrt{f(x_n)})$ is independent of $E(K_{n-1})$, and thus $\operatorname{rank}(E(K_n)) \ge \log_2(|K_n:K|) + \operatorname{rank}(E(K))$, and if $E/K$ has complex multiplication then $\operatorname{rank}(E(K_n)) \ge 2\log_2(|K_n:K|) + \operatorname{rank}(E(K))$.

What function of $|K_n:K|$ is an upper bound to $\operatorname{rank}(E(K_n))$ for all towers $\{K_n\}$?  Is there an example with $\limsup \operatorname{rank}(E(K_n))/\log_2(|K_n:K|) \gt 1$ resp.${} \gt 2$ for fixed $E/K$ without resp. with complex multiplication?

Comment: I think it should possible to find a specific curve over rationals, such that you can show that (up to log factors) a positive proportion of quadratic twists with discriminant supported on the first $n$ primes have root number -1, giving a much higher lower bound than logarithmic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is a good idea to compare the growth of the rank to the degree. I would say that we have **excessive growth** in an extension $F/K$ if $$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}\rank E(F) - \rank E(K) > [F:K].$$
There is a conjecture, called the minimalistic conjecture for twists in [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.07883) that implies that if $K=\mathbb{Q}$ then for 100%  of curves $E$ there is no excessive growth in a fixed $F/\mathbb{Q}$. To find growth of rank is therefore not so easy, but a well studied question. Maybe [this article by Mazur and Rubin](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703363) is a good place to start.

Of course it is easy to construct large excessive growth for quadratic extensions. If $F/K$ is quadratic then $\rank E(F) - \rank E(K) = \rank \breve{E}(K)$ where $\breve{E}/K$ is the quadratic twist of $E$ corresponding to $F/K$. So over $\mathbb{Q}$, we can have growth of 28 by taking $E$ a twist of a curve of rank at least 28. It should not be hard to prove that for a given $E/\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$ there are $n$ quadratic twists with coprime discriminant all of positive rank. That would give a multiquadratic extension  with rank growth at least equal to the degree. For general successive quadratic extensions, i.e., a general $2$-group, this might be harder. However the methods coming from root numbers often allow to find local conditions, especially in even order groups, which force the rank to grow as a positive proportion of the rank. See the first link above.

Another famous example in which the rank grows at least as fast as the degree are anti-cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions. Let $p>2$ be a prime and $K$ a quadratic imaginary field. There is a unique extension $F/K$ such that its Galois group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, it is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, but the group $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is not abelian (but infinite dihedral). This is formed of extensions $F_n/K$ which are cyclic of degree $p^n$. Under suitable conditions on an elliptic curve $E$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, e.g. the Heegner hypothesis, one can show that the rank of $E(F_n)$ is equal to $[F_n:K]+C$ for a constant $C$ if $n$ is sufficiently large. This growth is produced by Heegner points that can be shown to be independent. This was done by Cornut and Vatsal as explained in [these videos](https://archive.org/details/07edixhoven37). This gives a proven example with
$\bigl(\rank E(F_n) - \rank E(K) \bigr)/[F_n:K]$ converging to $1$. By taking the non-Galois subfield of degre $p^n$, we also get this limit equal to $1$ over $K=\mathbb{Q}$.

I don't think I have ever seen an infinite tower such that $$\frac{\rank E(F_n) - \rank E(K)}{[F_n:K]}$$ has a $\limsup$ larger than $1$. There are examples of finite extensions other than the quadratic case above in which the rank grows quicker, but they are relatively rare. My favourite is [this curve](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/5692a1/) of conductor 5692 and rank $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. It has rank $6$ over the cubic cyclic field with $\alpha^2-3\alpha+1=0$. For cyclic fields of prime degree larger than $5$, it should be very hard if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Wuthrich.  The $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions example of Cornut and Vatsal beats my example for rank growth and I'll look at the videos.    For a quadratic extension $F/\mathbb{Q}$ should the minimalist conjecture say $$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}\rank E(F) - \rank E(\mathbb{Q}) < 2 $$ for 100% of $E/\mathbb{Q}$ since it's conjectured 50% of  elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ have rank 0 and 50% have rank 1?  Given a tower of quadratic extensions, would you guess that for 100% of elliptic curves over the base, the rank increases by 0 in 50% of the extensions and by 1 in 50%?

Comment: The minimalistic conjecture for a $2$-group would only imply that the rank is 100% of the times less than the degree. The 50/50 is not generally true in all quadratic extensions as seen in https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.4027